# how to change starting position of a sphere in threejs

Tags: three.js

I created a 3D Earth using three.js that rotates, but the problem is that it starts spinning over the ocean.
i triedto change starting position using matrixWorld but didn't change anything
can someone help plz
here is my js:

...
const earthgeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.344,64,32);

```
            const eatrhmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                roughness: 1,
                metalness:0,
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('static/img/earthmap1k.jpg'),
                bumpMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('static/img/earthbump.jpg'),
                bumpScale: 0.3,
            });

            const earthmesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthgeometry,eatrhmaterial);
            earthmesh.position.set (0.49,0.035,0.58);
            earthmesh.matrixWorld.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 100));
```

...

Comment: Set initial value of rotation on Y-axis to Math.PI * 0.5, for example. `earthmesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5;`

Comment: can you elaborate more on the issue? what ocean does it start spinning over, do you have a screenshot? I am assuming you are rotating your earth material and you have a secondary sphere for the ocean

Comment: Hi @Mouhcin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you set a position, you can set a rotation of your object.

```js
const earthgeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.344,64,32);

const earthmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
//material definition here
});

const earthmesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthgeometry,earthmaterial);
earthmesh.position.set (0.49,0.035,0.58);
earthmesh.rotation.set (0,1.1,0);//or any other values
```

remember :

1. rotation are in radians: 360° = 2*Math.PI
2. Y axis is the vertical one

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer